# Unable to makemigrations in Django

Tags: django, makemigrations

**Problem statement:**

- I am trying to create a new model in a new file - `app1/models/model2.py`
- I dont see any error when I try to makemigrations.
- But Django doesnt detect any changes.
- If I put the same code in my previous file `app1/models/model1.py` - makemigrations works.
- I have tried - `python manage.py makemigrations app1` & `python manage.py makemigrations`

My basic model:

```
from django.db import models


class Xyz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I tried through pycharm & normal terminal. I am using UBuntu 20.04LTS.

I deleted all migration files then reran `makemigrations` for `app1` , it only picked old changes. did not pick new `Xyz` model.

So perhaps there is something wrong in the way I am creating this new model2.py file. But I am creating it normally like model1.py. I even tried to copy paste and rename the same file.
All my folder have **init**.py in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing the `app1.models.model2.Xyz` class to the `app1/models/__init__.py` as it was resolved on my side.

app/models/model2.py

```
from django.db import models


class Xyz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

### Run 1: Unsuccessful

app/models/__init__.py

```
from models.model1 import *
```

Make migrations

```
$ python3 app/manage.py makemigrations
(0.000) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.000) SELECT VERSION(); args=None
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.000) SHOW FULL TABLES; args=None
No changes detected
```

### Run 2: Successful

app/models/__init__.py

```
from models.model1 import *
from models.model2 import Xyz  # Add this line
```

Make migrations

```
$ python3 app/manage.py makemigrations
(0.000) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.000) SELECT VERSION(); args=None
(0.000) SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; args=None
(0.000) SHOW FULL TABLES; args=None
Migrations for 'app':
  app/migrations/0002_xyz.py
    - Create model Xyz
```